# Pipeline design and timing issues

Tags: vhdl

We are working on a pipelined processor written in VHDL, and we have some issues with timing, synchronization and registers on the simulator (the code does not need to be synthesizable, because we going to run it only on the simulator).

Imagine we have two processor stages, A and B, with a pipeline register in the middle:

- Processor stage A is combinatorial and does not depend on clock
- The pipeline register R, is a register, and therefor, changes its state at clock rising edge.
- Processor stage B is a complex stage and has its own state machine, and, therefor, changes its state and does operations inside a VHDL process, governed by clock rising edge.

The configuration would be as follows

```
   _______   ___   _______
   |     |   | |   |     |
---|  A  |---|R|---|  B  |---
   |_____|   |_|   |_____|
```

With this configuration, there is a timing problem:

- t = 0: A gets data, and does its operations
- t = 1: At rising edge, R updates its data with the output of A.
- t = 2: At rising edge, B gets the values of R, and updates its status and gives an output.

We would like to have B changing its state and generating an output at t = 1, but we also need the register in the middle to make the pipeline work.

A solution would be to update the R register on falling edge. But then, we are assuming that all processor stages run in half a clock cycle, and the other half is a bit useless.

How is this problem usually solved in pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, just saying from personal experience in this field: never develop your own cpu, unless you are a freaking genius and have another few of your kind to verify your work and port a compiler.

To your problem:
a) A cutset technique is usually used to insert pipeline stages in the design. When implemented properly, you only need to solve control hazards
b) Model your stages not with registers inbetween but with 1-deep transparent FIFOs - you will get automatic stall management for free and it is easier to reason about pipelines
c) Bypass register R. Use data from A to register it in R and in B.

If none above helped, redesign B and/or hire a hardware developer that is used to reason about concurrent hardware.

Comment: I didn't mention that this is a class assignment. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ah ok :) Then just use A directly in B, bypassing R (but still use the registered value for other stages)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This might work in a simulator (still not tried). But, if this was to be synthesized (it's not going to be, but I'm just curious), how would you manage that glitches in output values of A may propagate through the bypass to module B in the middle of one clock cyle?

Comment: You don't manage them, you'll just have to have clock period long enough to settle them (so that output of B is registered with a stable value). This is the reason long logic paths influence your maximum frequency and this is why pipelining exists (to shorten them).

Answer (score 0):

After talking to quite a few people, I think we found the proper solution to the problem.

The stage B, which has its own state machine, should not have a VHDL process activated on rising edge. It should have the state of the state machine as a signal that is stored on register R.

In more detail, these new signals should be added:

- `state`: current state of the state machine, output from R, input to B
- `state_next`: next state of the state machine, input to R, output from B

Which means that `state` is changed for `state_next` each rising edge, and B can now work without a process.